# Problem in using scipy.spatial.cKDTree or queryBallPoint with random 2d points using nearest neighbors between two datasets

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have P_0 points spread randomly in a 2d box. Then I divide them in two groups S and I. If some points of S come too close to I, they are deleted from the S group and added to the I group. The problem I am facing is that sometimes they are not correctly deleted from S, but they are properly added to I. Hence, the total number of points keeps erroneously growing.
Here is the code:

```
from scipy.spatial import cKDTree
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
P_0 = 100 # initial susceptible population
# dimensions of box
Lx = 5.0
Ly = 5.0
# generate P_0 random points inside box
X = np.random.uniform(0, Lx, P_0)
Y = np.random.uniform(0, Ly, P_0)
pts = np.column_stack((X, Y)) # array of 2d points
S = np.arange(10, P_0) # indices of the susceptible
I = np.arange(10) # indices of the infected
# Divide points into infected and susceptible groups
r_I = pts[I]
r_S = pts[S]
tree = cKDTree(r_S)
# idx represents the indices to points in r_S which are closer than r to
# points in r_I
idx = tree.query_ball_point(r_I, r=0.4) 
idx = np.hstack(idx) # flatten the lists into one numpy array
idx = idx.astype(int) # Make sure idx indices have int type
print idx

# plot points
plt.figure()
plt.plot (r_S[:, 0], r_S[:, 1], 'bo') # plot all r_S points
plt.plot (r_S[idx, 0], r_S[idx, 1], 'ko') # color those points nearest to r_I
plt.plot (r_I[:, 0], r_I[:, 1], 'ro') # identify the r_I points
print len(S), len(I), len(S)+len(I)
I= np.append(I, S[idx]) # add the closest points to I
S = np.delete(S, idx) # delete the closest points from S

# points in r_I
idx = tree.query_ball_point(r_I, r=0.4) 
idx = np.hstack(idx) # flatten the lists into one numpy array
idx = idx.astype(int) # Make sure idx indices have int type
print idx

# plot points
plt.figure()
plt.plot (r_S[:, 0], r_S[:, 1], 'bo') # plot all r_S points
plt.plot (r_S[idx, 0], r_S[idx, 1], 'ko') # color those points nearest to r_I
plt.plot (r_I[:, 0], r_I[:, 1], 'ro') # identify the r_I points
print len(S), len(I), len(S)+len(I)
I= np.append(I, S[idx]) # add the closest points to I
S = np.delete(S, idx) # delete the closest points from S

plt.figure('S group')
plt.plot (pts[S, 0], pts[S, 1], 'bo') # plot the updated r_S points

plt.figure('I group')
plt.plot (pts[I, 0], pts[I, 1], 'ro') # plot the updated r_I points
print len(S), len(I), len(S)+len(I), len(idx)
plt.show()
```

So, I don't know why not all points in r_S closer than r, sometimes aren't deleted from S.
One might have to run the code a few times for the error to appear, or just increase P_0 to 1000 for example or increase the value of r. it might be a problem with idx and the way I am using numpy delete.

Answer (score 0):

You could double check your assumption by swapping the actions (doing a move by doing the deletion first and the addition second, only on a successful deletion) and testing the deletion in a separate variable.

Compare the resulting size after deletion with the original size of the group. If sizes match, no deletion had occurred (for whatever reason), which is a signal not to add something on the other side.

Then you could have a print of groups on the upper case and see the indexes which participate to shed some light into the tunnel.

Comment: Thanks for helping. I think I discovered the problem. It's in idx. Sometimes one point in S will be nearest neighbor to more than one point in I. I have just to eliminate the repeats in idx. when r was small, this rarely happened, but when I increase r this happens a lot.

Answer (score 0):

As I just commented, I just had to eliminate the duplicates in idx. 
I added the line

```
idx = np.unique(idx)
```

just below idx = idx.astype(int)